# Find and replace in files fails

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to do find and replace in a file using following approach.

```
Function Find-Replace ($FileFullpath, $FindString, $ReplacementString) {

   Get-Content $FileFullpath | 
   Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $FindString, $ReplacementString } |  
   Set-Content $FileFullpath

}

Find-Replace "c:\program files (x86)\MyProj\web.config" $OldServiceName $NewServiceName
```

But i am always getting error.

> Set-Content : The process cannot access the file 'c:\program files
>   (x86)\MyProj\web.config' because it is being used by another process.

The file is not opened any where. I think Get-content is yet to release the file.

Why it happens ? How to do find and replace in the same file without issue?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can't read and write to the same file while it's open. `Get-Content` opens the file for reading and, at the same time, `Set-Content` tries to write to it. Put the `Get-Content` call in parentheses; it will open the file, read its content and close it.

```
(Get-Content $FileFullpath) | ...
```

Comment: I was searching the result for half an hour and frustrated with failure. I raised this question and went for coffee. Now answer is here. Same thing happened few months ago. Striking thing is again Levy :)

Comment: Thanks @Samselvaprabu glad to help. You can find this in help too: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347736.aspx, take a look at the third example.