# Is it possible to create a new csv column with calculation while importing in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to be able to do something like This except -AddColumn is fictitious syntaxe :

```
Import-Csv in.csv -header Date,Time,O,H,L,C,V|select * -AddColumn median %{$_.median=($_.H + $_.L)/2}
```

What would be the real syntax or how to do it the easiest way ?

data file :

```
2015.08.09,20:45,1.09538,1.09546,1.09522,1.09524,74
2015.08.09,20:50,1.09523,1.09537,1.09505,1.09523,110
2015.08.09,20:55,1.09524,1.09546,1.09520,1.09526,165
2015.08.09,21:00,1.09526,1.09526,1.09495,1.09497,141
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Column to CSV Windows PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022017/add-column-to-csv-windows-powershell)

Comment: except I have a calculation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Foreach-Object` and `Add-Member` come to mind but a simpler solution would be to use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

```
Import-Csv in.csv -header Date,Time,O,H,L,C,V | select *, @{Name="median";Expression={([double]$_.H + [double]$_.L)/2}}
```

Don't forget to cast your numbers for mathematical calculations. Before it was trying to do something like this:

```
($_.H + $_.L)/2
("1.09538" + "1.09524")/2
(1.095381.09524)/2 # < that would not compute
```

Comment: I have updated with data file. That's weird median is empty, why ?

Comment: @user310291 That is my fault for not paying attention to you calculation. Import-csv casts everything to strings. updated