# Importing CSV adding a column using PowerShell in C#

Tags: c#, .net, csv, powershell

I have a fairly large CSV file (27MB) with at least 400,000 rows in it. I want to add a column to it, just like in [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17022017/4724142) and export it, except that I have to do it in C#. I have added the `System.Management.Automation` and the `Microsoft.PowerShell` namespaces. I would also like the new column to be the first column in the CSV. How might I be able to achieve this in the fastest way possible?

While the method used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-sharp) could work, I specifically do not want to use any custom libraries not provided by windows.

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Import-Csv " + csvFileName + " |Select-Object *,@{Name='Name' ;Expression = {'setvalue'}} | Export-Csv " + csvFileName + " -NoTypeInformation");
ps.Invoke();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing CSV files in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the `ps.AddCommand` to `ps.AddScript` and surrounding the csvFileName with single quotes. The modified code is as follows

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript("Import-Csv '" + csvFileName + "' |Select-Object *,@{Name='Name' ;Expression = {'setvalue'}} | Export-Csv '" + newCsvFileName + "' -NoTypeInformation");
ps.Invoke();
```