# CSV Manipulation with powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to replace all content of column A of a CSV  with current date `MMddyyyy` using PowerShell command(s)

Looked over plenty examples over past couple days, but cant find the right answer, somewhat new to powershell, having a unix background for 35 years!

my desired results would be a new CSV file with date in 1st column followed by all the other columns from source CSV.

`MMddyyyy`, all, other, fields, from, original, csv

Comment: also wouldn't mind doing it in perl if easier :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Column to CSV Windows PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022017/add-column-to-csv-windows-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in a file called your.csv and the contents are as follows:

```
ColA,ColB,ColC
somethingA,somethingB,SomethingC
somethingA,somethingB,SomethingC
somethingA,somethingB,SomethingC
somethingA,somethingB,SomethingC
somethingA,somethingB,SomethingC
somethingA,somethingB,SomethingC
```

An efficient way to do this is following a solution posted at [Add Column to CSV Windows PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022017/add-column-to-csv-windows-powershell). Here are the details following that method where you want to replace the first column and keep the remaining columns in order:

```
Import-Csv your.csv | 
  Select-Object -Property @{n="ColA";e={get-date -f MMddyyyy}},* -ExcludeProperty ColA |
    Export-Csv new.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

A less efficient alternative processes each row and makes the appropriate change. This will update the original `$file` variable with the new data, but will leave the original file unchanged. new.csv is the output file with all of the updates.

```
$file =  Import-Csv your.csv

Foreach ($row in $file) {
   $row.ColA = get-date -f MMddyyyy
}

$file | Export-Csv new.csv -NotypeInformation
```

Now, the contents of new.csv are as follows:

```
"ColA","ColB","ColC"
"04042019","somethingB","SomethingC"
"04042019","somethingB","SomethingC"
"04042019","somethingB","SomethingC"
"04042019","somethingB","SomethingC"
"04042019","somethingB","SomethingC"
"04042019","somethingB","SomethingC"
```

Comment: For static content added, a Select-Object ishould be more efficient. See [Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022017/add-column-to-csv-windows-powershell)

Comment: I made an update to reference that solution. Thanks