# how to prepend filename to every record in a csv?

Tags: powershell, command-line

**How do we prepend the filename to ALL the csv files in a specific directory?**

I've got a bunch of csv files that each look like this:

**ExampleFile.Csv**

```
2323, alex, gordon
4382, liza, smith
```

The output I'd like is:

```
ExampleFile.Csv, 2323, alex, gordon
ExampleFile.Csv, 4382, liza, smith
```

**How do we prepend the filename to ALL the csv files in a specific directory?**

I've attempted the following solution:

```
Get-ChildItem *.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $CSV = Import-CSV -Path $_.FullName -Delimiter ","
    $FileName = $_.Name

    $CSV | Select-Object *,@{E={$FileName}} | Export-CSV $_.FullName -NTI -Delimiter ","
}
```

However, this did not work because it was altering the first row. (My data does not have a header row). Also, this script will append to each record at the end rather than *prepend* at the beginning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Column to CSV Windows PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022017/add-column-to-csv-windows-powershell)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin would love to know more about why you think this is duplicative?

Comment: Have you _looked_ at the duplicate? It seems to me that the only difference between what you're asking and what the proposed duplicate is doing is _where_ in the record you're seeking to add the new property...

Comment: my point exactly ;). there are several differences,

Comment: The same technique will work. In your case, the "computed" value is the file name that the data is coming from, and you'll simply put that value _before_ the * in the `Select-Object`.  Read and understand; if you simply blindly accept code that you do not understand as an answer, how are you going to know that it's not malicious?

Comment: im sorry it might be obvious to you, but i have almost no experience with powershell. perhaps there's also a big intelligence gap between the two of us

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the column header name I think. Take a look at the duplicate (or original, rather) and see Shay's answer. Your `Select-Object` should look like:

```
$CSV | Select-Object @{Name='FileName';Expression={"$filename"}},* | Export-Csv -Path $FileName -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ','
```

That worked fine for me with multiple CSVs in a directory when using the rest of your sample code verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

If your files do not have headers and the column count is unknown or unpredictable, you can read each line with `Get-Content`, make the changes, and then use `Set-Content` to make the update.

```
Get-ChildItem *.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $Filename = $_.Name
    $Fullname = $_.FullName
    $contents = Get-Content -Path $Fullname | Foreach-Object {
        "{0}, {1}" -f $Filename,$_
    }
    $contents | Set-Content -Path $Fullname
}
```