# Remove content, while keeping first top line powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a sample.txt file where I would like to remove the content, except for it first top line.

My sample.txt file looks like this:

```
1.dslkjfladsdjgmvjfgmldskbm;sldkvmg,;sdlmg;msj,;sdrl
2.dlkjfsadfjmsal;jsalv;dsvmdsfkgmrg,pvtpvhtphb[h.[y
3.fljsafckg,ksd,v;vyklt;vlkbmyulnmktr,ouf,f/.n,
4.dflcajsmglsdv;ks'ítb;pjk.'gpjnuk. uo.hulmk,vgjhumk.'l
```

I would like the output result to look like following:

```
1.dslkjfladsdjgmvjfgmldskbm;sldkvmg,;sdlmg;msj,;sdrl
```

I have tried these commands but output clears the entire file.

```
Clear-Content C:\sample.txt | where { $_.length -gt 2}| Set-Content C:\sample.txt

Clear-Content C:\sample.txt | Select -first 2 | Set-Content C:\sample.txt
```

Could someone please advise what am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

From [the documentation for the `Clear-Content` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849853.aspx):

> The Clear-Content cmdlet deletes the contents of an item, such as deleting the text from a file, but it does not delete the item. As a result, the item exists, but it is empty.

By using `Clear-Content` you are deleting the contents of `sample.txt` without reading it.  Instead, you want to use `Get-Content`:

```
(Get-Content C:\sample.txt -First 1) | Set-Content C:\sample.txt
```

Using the `-First` parameter (alias of `-TotalCount`) of the [`Get-Content` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849787.aspx) works much the same as `Select-Object -First` but allows `Get-Content` to stop reading the file as soon as we have the number of lines we need; `1`, not `2`, is passed to retrieve only the first line.  Note that the invocation of `Get-Content` must be surrounded in parentheses otherwise [`Set-Content` will complain that the file is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10480811/150605).  Alternatively, you can read the contents of the file into a variable first...

```
$firstLine = Get-Content C:\sample.txt -First 1
$firstLine | Set-Content C:\sample.txt
```

...or do a "safe overwrite" by outputting the filtered text to another file first, then overwrite the original...

```
Get-Content C:\sample.txt -First 1 | Set-Content C:\sample.txt.tmp
Move-Item C:\sample.txt.tmp C:\sample.txt -Force
```

Comment: Don't forget `Get-Content -TotalCount 1`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Good point.  I knew there was a way to more efficiently limit the number of lines read but was looking for it in [the wrong place](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847788.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

(gc C:\sample.txt |select -first 1)|out-file C:\sample.txt

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I finally succeed applying the following codes:

```
(Get-Content C:/sample.txt -TotalCount 1) | Set-Content C:\sample.txt
```

Thanks
Manu

Comment: I don't mean to be lobbying for my answer...but this is the same as my first code snippet.  `-First` is an alias of the `-TotalCount` parameter of `Get-Content`, which is stated in my answer.