# Powershell find and replace fails as file is used by another process

Tags: powershell

In a for loop, I search for various patterns in a file and replace them with pre-defined token :

`((Get-Content -path $file -Raw)  -replace $pattern, $tokenValue) | Set-Content -Path $file`

This works sometimes but at other times it fails with the error :

`The process cannot access the file 'my-file' because it is being used by another process.`

I see the fix for this is to used the pipe | ([Find and replace in files fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480673/find-and-replace-in-files-fails))  but I am already doing this. What could be another reason for this issue ?

Here's the full snippet:

```
 foreach ($variable in $variables) {
        $token = $variable.Value.replace("__", "")

        if ([bool]($group.variables.PSobject.Properties.name -eq $token)){
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkGreen "Match found ! token $token"

            $tokenValue = $group.variables | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $token | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkGreen  "replacing " $variable.Value " with $tokenValue"
          
            ((Get-Content -path $file -Raw)  -replace $pattern, $tokenValue) | Set-Content -Path $file
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the file open in another application?

Comment: no the file is created by the script and not used by any other process other than the one of the script itself. I will try @AdminOfThings suggestion

Comment: Try `$content=((Get-Content -path $file -Raw)  -replace $pattern, $tokenValue)` and `Set-Content -Path $file -Value $content` instead of using the pipe

Comment: @AdminOfThings suggestion gives same error. I am now trying Adis1102 suggestion.

Comment: I think the issue happens when you haven more than 1 pattern in your file: Get-Content opens, read finds the 1st pattern and closes the file -  sends it to Set-Content, then Get-Content wants to open again to continue the seach, but cannot do it cause Set-Content is still writing...

Comment: @Adis1102, I have updated my question with full relevant code. I don't think that is the problem because the next iteration should not start unless Set-Content is done

Comment: Why even write to the same file multiple times? Just update the content in memory and write to the file at the end. `$content = Get-Content -path $file -Raw` before the loop. Then update `$content` with `$content = $content -replace $pattern, $tokenValue` during the loop. Then after the loop, update the file `$content | set-content $file`.

Comment: Do you have antivirus software installed? That could potentially be locking the file after the first write while it scans it, which would prevent the next write from happening...

Comment: @AdminOfThings, you are right ! I don't know why I coded it like this, but making the change you suggested fixed the problem :)  Maybe you can post it as an answer ?